# Access Image in Private GitHub Repository to Embed in Leaflet for R PopUp

Tags: r, github

I am creating a map in R Leaflet that has images in the marker popups.  The images are stored in a private repository and drawn in using `img src` in HTML.  It works fine when it is a public repository:

```
library(leaflet)
#use example quake dataset
data(quakes)
#load image url from public repo that will be in popup
senor.cat <- paste(sep = "<br/>",
               "<b><img  src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mvevans89/LabNotebook/gh-pages/senorcat.jpg' height='100', width='75'></a></b>",
               "Senor Cat")
#map
leaflet(data = quakes[1:20,]) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, popup=senor.cat)
```

However, once I try to use a private repository it no longer works.

If I manually look up the raw URL with the appended ?token.. at the end, it will work (see below), but I have over 150 images that I would have to manually copy the URL of and once the tokens change, the URLs will no longer work.

```
senor.token <- paste(sep = "<br/>", 
"<b><img src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mvevans89/score/master/score-tza/map-plots/senorcat.jpg?token=AOgHwYukKnhm4QQqNNiHardu-u5MmC6Nks5WxkmzwA%3D%3D' height='100', width='75'></a></b>",
"Senor Cat")
leaflet(data = quakes[1:20,]) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, popup=senor.token)
```

Is this something I need to try and access using an OAuth token? Any ideas how to put it inside the `img src` call? Or just a better way to embed private github repo images in HTML? Or maybe even scrape the folder in my repo for all of the raw url's with tokens?

Answer (score 1):

You could use GitHub's Personal API tokens. There is a blog post about this from 2013: https://github.blog/2013-05-16-personal-api-tokens/

1. Go to https://github.com/settings/tokens to create a token, for example `b9d03a4ec49cad90bfc1c7fec2fbbf49790cf32d`.
2. You can now access the images in your private repository with

   ```
   https://b9d03a4ec49cad90bfc1c7fec2fbbf49790cf32d@raw.githubusercontent.com/mvevans89/score/master/score-tza/map-plots/senorcat.jpg
   ```

**Be aware:** Make sure nobody will have access to this token or they could access your repositories, too.

Comment: It doesn’t work in browser ? Any idea why ?